# Sefer Nestor Hakomer Online?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, internet, christianity

Does anyone know if it is possible to find the (hebrew) text of [Sefer Nestor Hakomer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Book_of_Nestor_the_Priest), an old jewish apologetic book, available for free online?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/34172) it is on Hebrewbooks.

Comment: The author seem to be really someone else.